# Retreiving httpResponse StatusCode from API

Tags: rest

This is the HTTP response I send from my API if there's an error.

```
return new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage() { StatusCode = (System.Net.HttpStatusCode)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ReasonPhrase = "Incoming element is null" };
```

which Postman sees correctly as

```
"statusCode": 400,
"reasonPhrase": "Incoming element is null",
```

So the API code is fine, however, when I call the API from my console application the HttpWebResponse using the following

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/");
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

`httpResponse.StatusCode` is `OK`.

How do I get the returned `StatusCode` from the API to be accessible/visible in the calling console application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `httpResponse` is the "I am connected" response not the returned response from the API, that was in accessed using

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
    string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

to stream the result back from the API which was the JSON response being picked up by Postman.

So instead I deserialised the returned JSON into an object and used that to make my validation checks, like so.   First my storage class

```
public class ReturnedJSONModel {
    public System.Net.HttpStatusCode statusCode { get; set; }
    public string reasonPhrase { get; set; }
}
```

then this to populate it and handle the response (note this is a Console program so uses `Console.WriteLine` to report success/failure.

```
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
        string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        ReturnedJSONModel objJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReturnedJSONModel>(result);
        switch(objJSON.statusCode) {
            case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted:
                Console.WriteLine("Success : " + objJSON.reasonPhrase);
                break;
            case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest:
                Console.WriteLine("BadRequest : " + objJSON.reasonPhrase);
                break;
            case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable:
                Console.WriteLine("ServiceUnavailable : " + objJSON.reasonPhrase);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown error : " + objJSON.reasonPhrase);
                break;
        }
    }
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Error StatusCode = " + httpResponse.StatusCode);
}
```